Image fits on css block
I'm trying to fit this image without use hard code on height block (css class height), because when the resolution changes, the image does not stay at the base of the css block. I have already tested many things, like inherit, auto e others css parameters.
<div class="shape"></div>
<div id="banner">
  <img src="src/images/hero1.png" alt="" id="banner">
</div>

#banner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: start;
    justify-content: end;
    width: 70%;
    z-index: 2;
}

#banner img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 90%;
}

.shape {
    background-color: var(--color-primary-2);
    width: 50%;
    height: 87.4%;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 40% 30% 20% 20%;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center; 
}


Image with my monitor resolution


Image with others monitor resolution




unrelated, but using the same id (banner) twice is not valid in html. It usually works fine in most browsers but can lead to bugs, so you probably should avoid it.

You are missing object-position:bottom and align-item:end. Also, since the image is not a child element of the shape, they have to have the same size and position.


/*
There's no way to inherit from a sibling element. 
You could set custom properties on common ancestor if wanting to prevent duplicate.
*/
#banner {
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 87.4%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.shape {
  background-color: #b3e4ff;
  width: 50%;
  height: 87.4%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 40% 30% 20% 20%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#banner img {
  max-height: 90%;
  max-width: 70%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: bottom;
}
<div class="shape"></div>
<div id="banner">
  <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/XZ4V5.jpg" alt="">
</div>



That being said, if you move the image under shape, the CSS can be much simpler and more robust.


.shape {
  background-color: #b3e4ff;
  width: 50%;
  height: 87.4%;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 40% 30% 20% 20%;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: center; remove if there's nothing else needing this*/ 
  /*align-items: center; remove if there's nothing else needing this*/
}

#banner {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: end;
  justify-content: center;
}

#banner img {
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: bottom;
  max-height: 90%;
  width: 70%;
}
<div class="shape">
  <div id="banner">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/XZ4V5.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
</div>



